# Transformation method in finding p.d.f?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question:**

The probability distribution function is $f(x,y)= 12xy^{(1-y)} $ where $0< x, y < 1$

And $z=xy^2$ Then what is the probability distribution function of $z =f(z)$?

I solve the question by using transformation method. And the solution is below.

I did it but I'm confused. Please check whether my solution is correct or not. Thank you.

[image]